# Set 24x24 and 32 bit images for dynamically created CMFCToolBarButtons

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, dialog, icons, toolbar

In order to add a toolbar to my MFC dialog baced class, I tried all ways of adding `resources>toolbars` but they didn't work. Finally I came up to the point to create a toolbar dynamically. This is the code that I have used:

**Resource.h**

```
#define IDB_PanTbrBtn                   139
#define IDB_NewTbrBtn                   140
#define IDB_ZoomInTbrBtn                141
#define IDB_ZoomOutTbrBtn               142
#define IDC_FirstToolBar                1011
#define IDC_NEWTBRBTN                   1012
#define IDC_ZOOMINTBRBTN                1013
#define IDC_ZOOMOUTTBRBTN               1014
#define IDC_PANTBRBTN                   1015
```

**InitialJobProject2Dlg.h** : header file for the dialog baced project

```
#pragma once
#include "WndResizer.h"
#include "afxdlgs.h"
#include "FilesWorkFlow.h"
#include "OpenGLControl.h"  
CWndResizer m_resizer;
CMFCToolBar m_FirstToolBar;
FilesWorkFlow *m_files;
COpenGLControl *m_oglWindow;
```

**InitialJobProject2Dlg.cpp** :  the codes related to the toolbar in the function `OnInitDialog()`

```
    bool bAnchored = false;
    bAnchored = m_resizer.Hook(this);
    assert(bAnchored);

bool ToolbarCreated = m_FirstToolBar.CreateEx(this, AFX_DEFAULT_TOOLBAR_STYLE, 100 );

if(ToolbarCreated)
{
    m_FirstToolBar.SetDlgCtrlID(IDC_FirstToolBar);
    bAnchored = m_resizer.SetAnchor(IDC_FirstToolBar,ANCHOR_LEFT | ANCHOR_TOP);
    assert(bAnchored);

    m_FirstToolBar.SetPaneStyle(m_FirstToolBar.GetPaneStyle() & ~(CBRS_GRIPPER|CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC|CBRS_BORDER_ANY));

    VERIFY(m_FirstToolBar.LoadBitmapW(IDB_NewTbrBtn));
    VERIFY(m_FirstToolBar.GetImages()->Load(IDB_NewTbrBtn,nullptr,TRUE));
    int imageIndex = m_FirstToolBar.GetImages()->GetCount();
    m_FirstToolBar.InsertButton(CMFCToolBarButton(IDC_NEWTBRBTN,imageIndex));

    VERIFY(m_FirstToolBar.LoadBitmapW(IDB_PanTbrBtn));
    VERIFY(m_FirstToolBar.GetImages()->Load(IDB_PanTbrBtn,nullptr,TRUE));
    imageIndex = m_FirstToolBar.GetImages()->GetCount();
    m_FirstToolBar.InsertButton( CMFCToolBarButton( IDC_PANTBRBTN,imageIndex));

    VERIFY(m_FirstToolBar.LoadBitmapW(IDB_ZoomInTbrBtn));
    VERIFY(m_FirstToolBar.GetImages()->Load(IDB_ZoomInTbrBtn,nullptr,TRUE));
    imageIndex = m_FirstToolBar.GetImages()->GetCount();
    m_FirstToolBar.InsertButton( CMFCToolBarButton( IDC_ZOOMINTBRBTN,imageIndex));

    VERIFY(m_FirstToolBar.LoadBitmapW(IDB_ZoomOutTbrBtn));
    VERIFY(m_FirstToolBar.GetImages()->Load(IDB_ZoomOutTbrBtn,nullptr,TRUE));
    imageIndex = m_FirstToolBar.GetImages()->GetCount();
    m_FirstToolBar.InsertButton(CMFCToolBarButton(IDC_ZOOMOUTTBRBTN,imageIndex));

    CSize size = m_FirstToolBar.CalcFixedLayout( FALSE, TRUE );
    m_FirstToolBar.SetWindowPos( NULL, 0, 0, size.cx + 10, size.cy + 10 , SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER );
}
```

this is my project's resource view:
[image]
and this one is the res folder of my program:
[image]
images that I want to be shown as the icons of toolbar buttons are 48x48 ,32 bit depth bitmap images but I had the same problem with 24x24 ones
**The problem is when I run the program:**
[image]
IT's clear that there is just one button as the toolbar button but I have inserted four buttons dynamically as you see in the code.
and the image is not shown even for this known button.
**My code does not have any compiler or run-time error so I don't understand what is happening and whats the problem?**
**and since I'm new to MFC(this is my first program of MFC) I didn't know that adding a toolbar to a dialog-based application is such a hard task!!!! **

**So I created a dialog-based project at start and now that my program has been developed, I do need a toolbar**
please help me. this is the forth question I have posted about **adding a toolbar on a dialog based MFC application.

[after writing the code to add a toolbar to a dialog-based mfc the dialog doesn't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073052/after-writing-the-code-to-add-a-toolbar-to-a-dialog-based-mfc-the-dialog-doesnt)

[My toolbar on a dialog based mfc application is not shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074632/my-toolbar-on-a-dialog-based-mfc-application-is-not-shown)

[having trouble with LoadToolBarEx function of the CMFCToolBar class and set ID for the COpenGLControl class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078494/having-trouble-with-loadtoolbarex-function-of-the-cmfctoolbar-class-and-set-id-f)

But the problem has not been completely solved yet?

**Please introduce me a good reference that has taught adding toolbars to the MFC dialogs step by step from the scratch and has been useful for yourself**
Oh and if there's a need to my project, it is [downloadable here](http://www.4shared.com/rar/qs1WCMNU/InitialJobProject2.html)

---

as @Edward Clements suggested I changed the code to this but nothing changed.

```
    VERIFY(m_FirstToolBar.LoadBitmap(IDB_NewTbrBtn));
    m_FirstToolBar.InsertButton(CMFCToolBarButton(IDC_NEWTBRBTN,1));

    VERIFY(m_FirstToolBar.LoadBitmap(IDB_PanTbrBtn));
    m_FirstToolBar.InsertButton( CMFCToolBarButton( IDC_PANTBRBTN,2));

    VERIFY(m_FirstToolBar.LoadBitmap(IDB_ZoomInTbrBtn));
    m_FirstToolBar.InsertButton( CMFCToolBarButton( IDC_ZOOMINTBRBTN,3));

    VERIFY(m_FirstToolBar.LoadBitmap(IDB_ZoomOutTbrBtn));
    m_FirstToolBar.InsertButton(CMFCToolBarButton(IDC_ZOOMOUTTBRBTN,4));
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, according to the MFC sources, `LoadBitmap()` [NOT `LoadBitmapW()`, that seems to happen because of VS Intellisense picking up a #define from WinUser.h] adds the bitmap to the image list, so calling `m_FirstToolBar.GetImages()->Load()` will load the image twice.

Secondly, the `InsertButton()` should specify the index of the image of the button, `m_FirstToolBar.GetImages()->GetCount()` will always point to an invalid index value.

```
VERIFY(m_FirstToolBar.LoadBitmap(IDB_NewTbrBtn));
VERIFY(m_FirstToolBar.LoadBitmap(IDB_PanTbrBtn));
VERIFY(m_FirstToolBar.LoadBitmap(IDB_ZoomInTbrBtn));
VERIFY(m_FirstToolBar.LoadBitmap(IDB_ZoomOutTbrBtn));

m_FirstToolBar.InsertButton(CMFCToolBarButton(IDC_NEWTBRBTN, 0));
m_FirstToolBar.InsertButton(CMFCToolBarButton(IDC_PANTBRBTN, 1));
m_FirstToolBar.InsertButton(CMFCToolBarButton(IDC_ZOOMINTBRBTN, 2));
m_FirstToolBar.InsertButton(CMFCToolBarButton(IDC_ZOOMOUTTBRBTN, 3));
```

Comment: thanks @Edward Clements but when I write `m_FirstToolBar.` there are only LoadBitmapW and LoadBitmapEx and because LoadBitmapEx does not know the first argument I have used LoadBitmapW

Comment: thanks @Edward Clements but no it doesn't have you seen [my project](http://www.4shared.com/rar/qs1WCMNU/InitialJobProject2.html) comment out the parts that uses FileWORKflow and COpenGLControl classes and dependencies for GDAL and OpenGL Llibrary and it weel work on your system I think also have you seen [my another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097896/how-to-create-toolbars-in-an-mfc-dialog-based-application) the file that I have attached to it is the one I found on the web and can be run on every computer.

Comment: sorry, I answer specific questions as I can, I do not load other people's projects -- is the problem in this question solved?

Comment: no not solved but according to your answer on my [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097896/how-to-create-toolbars-in-an-mfc-dialog-based-application) I will try to solve it.thanks for your paying attention

Comment: @EdwardClements Sir can you please take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65053911/how-should-i-change-the-imagedoesnt-matter-the-type-of-the-button-in-the-tool) if you have time? It is similar to this but I am stuck for several days on the image of toolbar buttons in MFC. Thanks in advance...

Comment: what are IDC_NEWTBRBTN and other IDs because in my case the TOOLBAR is empty don't have buttons and I try to create them dynamically and set the bitmap to them like in this example

Comment: Should I create new toolbar with X buttons number and then set its bitmaps like here explained with insert button?