# how to create toolbars in an MFC dialog-based application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, dialog, icons, toolbar

I wonder how this guy has created this toolbar on the program:
[image]
this is a modeless dialog created by the guy, I think:  [image]
but my dialog is a modal one. I don't think it makes a lot of change!
and this the code written by him to use the toolbar supplied in the res folder:

**MainFrm.h**

```
protected:  // control bar embedded members
CMFCMenuBar       m_wndMenuBar;
CMFCToolBar       m_wndToolBar;
CMFCStatusBar     m_wndStatusBar;
CMFCToolBarImages m_UserImages;
```

**MainFrm.cpp** 
the code added in function:`CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)` to initialize the toolbar supplied in the resource:

```
if (!m_wndToolBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_TOP | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC) ||
    !m_wndToolBar.LoadToolBar(theApp.m_bHiColorIcons ? IDR_MAINFRAME_256 :     IDR_MAINFRAME))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create toolbar\n");
    return -1;      // fail to create
}

CString strToolBarName;
bNameValid = strToolBarName.LoadString(IDS_TOOLBAR_STANDARD);
ASSERT(bNameValid);
m_wndToolBar.SetWindowText(strToolBarName);

CString strCustomize;
bNameValid = strCustomize.LoadString(IDS_TOOLBAR_CUSTOMIZE);
ASSERT(bNameValid);
m_wndToolBar.EnableCustomizeButton(TRUE, ID_VIEW_CUSTOMIZE, strCustomize);

// Allow user-defined toolbars operations:
InitUserToolbars(NULL, uiFirstUserToolBarId, uiLastUserToolBarId);

if (!m_wndStatusBar.Create(this))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create status bar\n");
    return -1;      // fail to create
}
m_wndStatusBar.SetIndicators(indicators, sizeof(indicators)/sizeof(UINT));

// TODO: Delete these five lines if you don't want the toolbar and menubar to be dockable
m_wndMenuBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
m_wndToolBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
DockPane(&m_wndMenuBar);
DockPane(&m_wndToolBar);


// enable Visual Studio 2005 style docking window behavior
CDockingManager::SetDockingMode(DT_SMART);
// enable Visual Studio 2005 style docking window auto-hide behavior
EnableAutoHidePanes(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);

// Enable toolbar and docking window menu replacement
EnablePaneMenu(TRUE, ID_VIEW_CUSTOMIZE, strCustomize, ID_VIEW_TOOLBAR);

// enable quick (Alt+drag) toolbar customization
CMFCToolBar::EnableQuickCustomization();

if (CMFCToolBar::GetUserImages() == NULL)
{
    // load user-defined toolbar images
    if (m_UserImages.Load(_T(".\\UserImages.bmp")))
    {
        CMFCToolBar::SetUserImages(&m_UserImages);
    }

}

// enable menu personalization (most-recently used commands)
// TODO: define your own basic commands, ensuring that each pulldown menu has at least one basic command.
CList<UINT, UINT> lstBasicCommands;

lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_FILE_NEW);
lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_FILE_OPEN);
lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_FILE_SAVE);
lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_FILE_PRINT);
lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_APP_EXIT);
lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_EDIT_CUT);
lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_EDIT_PASTE);
lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_EDIT_UNDO);
lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_APP_ABOUT);
lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_VIEW_STATUS_BAR);
lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_VIEW_TOOLBAR);

CMFCToolBar::SetBasicCommands(lstBasicCommands);
```

**In fact something that I don't understand and has wasted my time two days and made me to post [four questions in this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090349/set-24x24-and-32-bit-images-for-dynamically-created-cmfctoolbarbuttons) is that after making a new toolbar supply here:
[image]
[image]
and leading to the toolbar editor
1-how can I create a new toolbar button here on the toolbar that has been supplied?
2-how can I change the shape of this button to the standard 24bit depth images or to a desired icon?
[image]
at last I want to have an image like this for my toolbar in my res folder and surely I want the buttons to be seperately clickable in my program's window.
[image]
If there's a need to the source of the project, [I have uploaded the guy's project here](http://www.4shared.com/rar/qRwWbx33/ddd2.html)

Answer (score 1):

The program with mainframe.cpp is not a modeless dialog, it is an MFC doc/view program that is designed to support a menu bar and toolbar.

A dialog-based program does not have the toolbar support designed in. The MFC sample program DLGCBR32 (in MSDN) shows how to put a toolbar on a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a question of reading the proper documentation, create new toolbar button: see MSDN  [Creating a New Toolbar Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eybeadd3.aspx/html) and [Toolbar Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfb33f94.aspx/html).

Changing the image depth of the buttons in a toolbar: load the bmp file associated with the toolbar (in the `Res` folder) in a bitmap editor (like Paint), save as a bmp with a different image depth, load the sln in VS and rebuild the project.