# How should I change the IMAGE(doesn't matter the type) of the button in the toolbar in MFC applications?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, toolbar

I know that this is stupid problem but I am stuck with it for the past 4 days. Why it is so complicated to just modify the toolbar in the MFC apps?

I create New Visual studio **MFC application** that is **dialog based**. I create new **Toolbar resource**. And then how should I set images(png, bitmap, jpeg...) or whatever type to be used in my toolbar?

I have set size to  w50 and h50 and I can draw inside the buttons. But I cant find way to use image.

Instead this 2 buttons that I have just tried if its working, I want to use 8 images that are in bitmap format and in png. I read somewhere that PNG is not supported by MFC applications so I converted to Bitmap.

[image]

I load my toolbar in the dialog app like this in the `OnInitDialog()` method:

```
    DWORD dwCtrlStyle = TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC;
    DWORD dwStyle = AFX_DEFAULT_TOOLBAR_STYLE;
    CMFCToolBar::m_dblLargeImageRatio = 1;

    if (m_ToolBar.CreateEx(this, dwCtrlStyle, dwStyle, CRect(1, 1, 1, 1), IDR_TOOLBAR1))
    {
        dwStyle = CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC;
        m_ToolBar.SetPaneStyle(m_ToolBar.GetPaneStyle() | dwStyle);
        CMFCToolBarInfo info;
        m_ToolBar.LoadToolBarEx(IDR_TOOLBAR1, info, FALSE);
        CSize   sizeToolBar = m_ToolBar.CalcFixedLayout(TRUE, TRUE);
        m_ToolBar.SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, sizeToolBar.cx, sizeToolBar.cy, SWP_NOACTIVATE | 
        SWP_NOZORDER);
        CPoint ptOffset(0, sizeToolBar.cy);
    }
```

Please if someone can help me I would be really grateful. The image format doesn't matter. I just want to put image in the toolbar.

This is my app currently:

[image]

**UPDATE:** I have tried this way. `ID_BUTTON_1` if the first button in the toolbar  and i tried to  change its image. But with this there is no button in the toolbar at the place for the first button. What I am doing Wrong?

```
VERIFY(m_toolbar.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP1));
CMFCToolBarButton mbutton;
mbutton.SetImage(m_toolbar.GetImages()->GetCount() - 1);
m_toolbar.ReplaceButton(ID_BUTTON_1, CMFCToolBarButton(ID_BUTTON_1, 0));
```

Comment: I  try to open the generated .bmp from the toolbar and edit it in photoshop and it can't be edited.

Comment: If you want your buttons to be visually distinct you probably shouldn't use `TBSTYLE_FLAT`.

Comment: thank you @MarkRansom,  i will remove it.

Comment: If you want images with full per-pixel alpha support, you need to supply 32bpp images. It appears that you are using 4bpp bitmaps. If you are using Photoshop to author your images, make sure to open and save them using MS Paint when done.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for comment. You are right I noticed that if I add bitmap converted from other website (png->bitmap) it give me error wrong format. But If I modify the already created .bmp with MS Paint it is ok and it can be opened.

Comment: So is that the right way to modify the toolbar, by placing X buttons that I need in the visual studio and then open the generated BMP modify it in paint  and save it.

Comment: You don't need to modify the image in MS Paint. Just opening and saving it unchanged will ensure that you get a valid BMP file.

Comment: Yes, but by modify I mean add my images for toolbar buttons in the bmp file generated by visualstudio

Comment: I am alittle confused. I thought I had recently answered a question that was similar to this a few days ago and now I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered this recently and can no longer find my answer. You can use PNG images for your toolbars. Under the hood you still use the BMP version for the resource editor to create your event handlers etc. But you can then add your PNG as a resource and then load it into your dialog.

For example, I call this in my `OnInitDialog` function:

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg::CreateToolbar()
{
    DWORD dwCtrlStyle = TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC;
    DWORD dwStyle = AFX_DEFAULT_TOOLBAR_STYLE;

    CMFCToolBar::m_dblLargeImageRatio = 1; // AJT v20.1.7 Bug fix
    if (m_ToolBar.CreateEx(this, dwCtrlStyle,
        dwStyle, CRect(1, 1, 1, 1), IDR_TOOLBAR))
    {
        dwStyle = CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC;
        m_ToolBar.SetPaneStyle(m_ToolBar.GetPaneStyle() | dwStyle);

        CMFCToolBarInfo info;

        info.m_uiColdResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;
        info.m_uiHotResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;
        info.m_uiLargeColdResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;
        info.m_uiLargeHotResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;

        m_ToolBar.LoadToolBarEx(IDR_TOOLBAR, info, FALSE);

        CSize   sizeToolBar = m_ToolBar.CalcFixedLayout(TRUE, TRUE);
        m_ToolBar.SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, sizeToolBar.cx, sizeToolBar.cy,
            SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);

        // Move all controls down
        CPoint ptOffset(0, sizeToolBar.cy);

        CRect  rcChild;
        CWnd* pwndChild = GetWindow(GW_CHILD);
        while (pwndChild)
        {
            if (pwndChild->GetSafeHwnd() != m_ToolBar.GetSafeHwnd())
            {
                pwndChild->GetWindowRect(rcChild);
                ScreenToClient(rcChild);
                rcChild.OffsetRect(ptOffset);
                pwndChild->MoveWindow(rcChild, FALSE);
            }
            pwndChild = pwndChild->GetNextWindow();
        }

        // Resize the window
        CRect rcWindow;
        GetWindowRect(rcWindow);
        rcWindow.bottom += sizeToolBar.cy;
        MoveWindow(rcWindow, FALSE);

    }
}
```

I don't know where my previous answer has gone to, else I would have flagged this as duplicate. #confused.

Comment: thank you for answer, you mean I should make PNG picture like toolbar size that has my icons in it and with your code it should display the PNG on my toolbar but, under the hood it will use the BMP for clicks events? Am I right?

Comment: in that case lets Say i need 9 buttons, First I would need in the toolbar resource to create 9 empty buttons and see the size and make the png with the same size(all 9 buttons together horizontally)

Comment: Yes. Just make your single PNG image with all buttons side by side.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much you saved me so much. Just a reminder for others that may have problem in future, when you create single png button for your buttons, use something like this [tool](https://www.filesmerge.com/merge-images) and resize it according to your toolbar instead of resizing and merging the buttons in paint like me :)